# Get Type of network interface via C#

Tags: c#, networking

I am querying the Network Interfaces of a Computer via C# as follows:

```
var interfaces = new List<string>();

var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
var moc = mc.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
{
    if (!(bool)mo["ipEnabled"])
        continue;

    string desc = (string) (mo["Description"]);

    interfaces.Add(desc);
 }

 return interfaces;
```

This Returns a list with Network Interfaces. The problem is that this contains the names of the Interfaces (Broadcom Family ...). But my users do not understand what kind of Interface this is (Ethernet, wifi, ...). Is it possible to figure out what type of a network interface this is? How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you using to get all network interfaces but in .NET we have [`NetworkInterface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface(v=vs.110).aspx) `class` in `System.Net.NetworkInformation` `namespace`.

You can get all interfaces with method [`NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.getallnetworkinterfaces(v=vs.110).aspx).

Then to understand what kind of interface you get you can check `NetworkInterfaceType` property. It's `enum` so for your purpose you can do something like this:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface netInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 
        || netInterface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
    {
        //your logic here
    }
}
```